# MySql GROUP_CONCAT() to print two rows as single row

Tags: mysql, subquery, group-concat

I have the following query:

```
 SELECT (
         SELECT j_name FROM judges WHERE sno IN (
            SELECT j_sno FROM bench_judges 
                    WHERE b_sno = p.wb_sno AND '2020-10-06' BETWEEN date_from AND date_to
                    )) AS judge 
FROM cases_proceedings p 
WHERE p.case_sno =  32505
ORDER BY p.sno 
DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

In `bench_judges` table, I have two rows according to the query. I need to print both the rows. For this I am using ***GROUP_CONCAT()*** like the following:

```
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(j_sno) FROM bench_judges
```

But it shows only one row. Where should I need to put the GROUP_CONCAT() to print both the rows as a single row?

Comment: Please add sample data and desired output as text to the question.

Comment: when you use `aggregate` function make sure to include `GROUP BY` clause with proper column name, otherwise only one record would be returned.